# How do I update each row in a column to each array value, instead of each row updating to the last array value?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

How do I update each row in the column to each array value, instead of each row updating to the last array value?

```
        foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET column_1='$value' WHERE column_2='value2'";
            mysqli_query($connDB, $sql);
        }
```

Input:

> 123 
> 456 
> 789

$array:

```
[0] => 123
[1] => 456
[2] => 789
```

Current result:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 789 | value2 |
| 789 | value2 |
| 789 | value2 |

What I want:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | value2 |
| 456 | value2 |
| 789 | value2 |

Comment: Does the table has an id column?

Comment: @ruleboy21 Yes, but the id values of the rows I'm updating will not always match the array keys.

Comment: Then you should change your `$array` to an associative array like `[2 => 123, 4 => 456]` for the keys to match the id column in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a third column to determine the status of the whole row. Then, during each loop, the status would update with a limit of 1 row at a time. Only rows with 'updating' status can be changed. ('locked' is the status column default)

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
        $status_update = "UPDATE table SET status='updating' WHERE column_2='value_2' AND status='locked' LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($connDB,$status_update);
        $value_update = "UPDATE table SET column_1='$value' WHERE status='updating'";
        mysqli_query($connDB, $value_update);
        $status_ready = "UPDATE table SET status='ready' WHERE column_2='value_2' AND status='updating'";
        mysqli_query($connDB, $status_ready);
    }
```

Results:

| column_1 | column_2 | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | value_2 | ready |
| 456 | value_2 | ready |
| 789 | value_2 | ready |

Answer (score 0):

You set $value1 in the query, change it to $value:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET column_1='$value' WHERE column_2='value2'";
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's just a typo in my question

Answer (score 0):

the problem is column_2 is not unique for each row. you must have unique value like id in a table for proper updating or deleting so you can select id of all rows with condition column_2=value2 and then update each row using its unique id

Comment: If there were 3 rows above these, then the unique id wouldn't matter since the array keys would be [0,1,2] and the row ids would be [3,4,5]